# Floor of a BST with recursive function in C

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to find the floor of a BST recursively.
This is the code:

```
node_t* floor_impl(node_t *node, const void *key, comparator_t key_cmp)
{
    if(node == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if(key_cmp(key, node->key) == 0)
    {
        return node->key;
    }
    else if(key_cmp(key, node->key) < 0)
    {
        return floor_impl(node->left, key, key_cmp);
    }
    else
    {
        node_t *floor = floor_impl(node->right, key, key_cmp);
        if(floor == NULL) { return NULL; }
        return key_cmp(node->key, floor->key) >= 0 ? node : floor;
    }
}
```

This function must return a node, which contains the floor.

But the result is a segmentation fault error.
I understood the theory behind the search of the floor, but not how to do it.

Comment: What happens when `floor == NULL` ?

Comment: Edit. Now if floor == NULL returns NULL. But now, in the test function, there is an assertion that fails: assert(key != NULL), so it returns NULL even if it should not

Comment: Please read the help on how to ask a question. It's for your own good. If you provide a very small _complete_ program that compiles and runs to produce the problem you're having, you're much more likely to get useful help.  Expecting people to guess the environment is often too much.  Not to mention that while you're creating the small program, it's likely you'll see the problem on your own, which is a much better way to learn than asking others to debug for you.